# Aligning buttons to the middle-right with GridBagLayout()

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

would like to align several buttons to about this location on a window with GridBagLayout(), though GridBagLayout is quite complex and I'm not sure how to go about this. How can I create such a layout?

Forgive me, I had to use ASCII because I do not have enough Rep to post an image.

```
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM?....+.. ....... MMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM?....Button...   MMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM?    .  .        MMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM?....Button...   MMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM?                MMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM?    Button      MMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM?      . ...     MMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM?    Button      MMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM?.... .......... MMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM?    Button      MMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

Answer (score 4):

> though GridBagLayout is quite complex

You don't have to use a GridBagLayout.

For example:

1. you could start with a `JPanel` than uses a `GridLayout`. Then add 4 buttons to the panel.
2. then you add this panel to the frame which uses a `BorderLayout` by using 
   `frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);`. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.
3. If you want extra spacing around the panel then you can add an `EmptyBorder` to the panel. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information.

Comment: The buttons are layered on top of an image though. If I put a panel over top of the image it would blot out part of it, unless there is some way to make the background color of the panel invisible.

Comment: You can use `panel.setOpaque(false)`.

Comment: I did what you said and I successfuly aligned it to the right side, however, the buttons hug the right side and touch the right side of the window. How can I move them more over to the left like my picture?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving this answer only for the specific Question: `Aligning buttons to the middle-right with GridBagLayout()`.

But for better use of layout Follow the Answer given by camickr.

===========================================================

Solution with `GridBagLayout()`

[image]

Below is the code with `GridBagLayout`

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ButtonsAlign extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ButtonsAlign frame = new ButtonsAlign();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public ButtonsAlign() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.1, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
       // gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};

        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        JButton btn_1 = new JButton("B1");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 20);
        gbc_comboBox.gridx = 2;
        gbc_comboBox.gridy = 0;
        gbc_comboBox.weightx=0.0;
        contentPane.add(btn_1, gbc_comboBox);

        JButton btn_2 = new JButton("B2");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnNewButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 20);
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 2;
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(btn_2, gbc_btnNewButton);
        setSize(200,300);//Only used to show bigger window
        //pack();
    }

}
```